# How does python interpret variable attributes in strings

Tags: python, python-ast

Suppose I have a string like this

```py
"Style.BRIGHT + 'BRIGHT' + '\\n' + Style.DIM + 'DIM' + '\\n' + Style.NORMAL + 'NORMAL'"
```

I try to print it directly

```py
from colorama import Style

s = "Style.BRIGHT + 'BRIGHT' + '\\n' + Style.DIM + 'DIM' + '\\n' + Style.NORMAL + 'NORMAL'"
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Style.BRIGHT + 'BRIGHT' + '\n' + Style.DIM + 'DIM' + '\n' + Style.NORMAL + 'NORMAL'
```

This is not the result I want, I want it to display the result in the terminal like this.

[image]

So I tried `eval` and it worked.

```py
from colorama import Style

s = "Style.BRIGHT + 'BRIGHT' + '\\n' + Style.DIM + 'DIM' + '\\n' + Style.NORMAL + 'NORMAL'"
print(eval(s))
```

Output:

```
BRIGHT
DIM
NORMAL
```

Although it succeeded, it seems to be unsafe, I also tried adding the global variable `{"Style": Style}`, so it might be relatively safe.

But maybe I'll extract properties in other variables, like this `x.y`, where x and y can be any value. So it feels like eval doesn't apply.

The answer of `@jfs` in this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) seems to be what I want, and I modified the program.

```py
from colorama import Style

import ast
import operator as op
# supported operators
operators = {ast.Add: op.add}


def eval_expr(expr):

    return eval_(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)


def eval_(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Constant):  # <number>
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):  # <left> <operator> <right>
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left), eval_(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
        return ast.unparse(node)
    else:
        raise TypeError(node)


s = "Style.BRIGHT + 'BRIGHT' + '\\n' + Style.DIM + 'DIM' + '\\n' + Style.NORMAL + 'NORMAL'"
print(eval_expr(s))
```

Output:

```
Style.BRIGHTBRIGHT
Style.DIMDIM
Style.NORMALNORMAL
```

In the program the string `Style.BRIGHT` is converted into an `ast.Attribute` object, I don't know how to get its value(`'\x1b[1m'`).

```py
In [1]: from colorama import Style

In [2]: Style.BRIGHT
Out[2]: '\x1b[1m'
```

If I use `eval(ast.unparse(node))` it succeeds, but if so why not just use `eval` directly...

So my question is:

- **How can I extract the primitive value corresponding to the `ast.Attribute` object?**

**Or is there any other way to interpret the string.**

---

The demo above is just one case, it can be applied to other cases.
For example, I want to define a macro, which is a string that adds and sums some properties of a class, which will be applied to other programs or processes.
Demo:

```py
class Base:

    a = 1
    b = 2


def get(cls):
    s = []
    for k, v in cls.__dict__.items():
        if k.startswith("_"):
            continue
        s.append(f"{cls.__name__}.{k}")
    return " + ".join(s)


s = get(Base)
print(s)

# Base.a + Base.b
```

Maybe my case is a bit unsatisfactory, but this problem may appear in a future scenario, maybe it's just me wanting to know how to deal with it.

Comment: `Style.BRIGHT` is a character defined by the `colorama` package that is interpreted by your terminal as "make anything after this character bright".

Comment: Why do you need to have the input as string and not use `Style` objects?

Comment: @mozway This is what I've seen from other places, and after trying it out, I'm curious how to use `ast.Attribute` and how to interpret the value corresponding to `x.y`.

Comment: "Suppose I have a string like this" - why do you *have* a string like that? The structure of that string is very tightly coupled to the specific `colorama` package you're using. If this string is coming from user input, you're tying your program's input format to the implementation details of your code in a way that makes it very awkward to change your implementation details. If the string *isn't* coming from user input, then why is it a string at all? And why is it in this format?

Comment: @ppig I provided another way to interpret the Styler codes, but it'd be hundred times better to use the correct object and not a string in the first place

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I added a bit of other possible scenarios at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

*NB.  It would be hundred times better to use the correct object and not a string in the first place, starting with correct input is almost always more explicit and efficient than trying to fix a broken input.*

If you have a string with arbitrarily complex operations, you will need to understand its grammar, which is exactly what `ast` is doing, or blindly (and potentially unsafely) evaluate it with `eval`.

That said, if you want to simplify your process **in the particular case you showed**, you need to do 3 things. 1- replace the `Styler` definitions with the string formatting codes they represent, 2- remove the quotes and +, 3- unescape the escaped newlines.

2 and 3 are quite easy to achieve, so I'll focus only on interpreting the codes here. You can use a regex to find the Styler definitions and `re.sub` to replace them safely with the actual formatting code.

```
from colorama import Style
import re

s = "Style.BRIGHT + 'BRIGHT' + '\\n' + Style.DIM + 'DIM' + '\\n' + Style.NORMAL + 'NORMAL'"

s2 = re.sub('Style\.[A-Z]+', lambda m: getattr(Style, m.group(0).split('.')[1]), s)
```

Output:

```
"\x1b[1m + 'BRIGHT' + '\\n' + \x1b[2m + 'DIM' + '\\n' + \x1b[22m + 'NORMAL'"
```

Comment: I added a bit of other possible scenarios at the end of the question.

Comment: This may be an alternative in certain scenarios.